# Stop user from leaving Processing application on OS X?

Tags: java, cocoa, macos, processing, kiosk

I want to display a full-screen Processing.org app (java) on a public computer on OS X.

Full-screen is easy enough, I can disable menu+dock via Info.plist.

How can I disable process switching (`cmd-tab`) and force quit popup, power popup, and other system hotkeys, etc.?   I want to make it bulletproof so the user is either stuck within my app or kicking the power cord out.

Comment: I'm no pro at this, but this doesn't sound like something that can be done with Java alone, that you would need some native code to lock the OS to your program.  Is this a program that the user would download and try to run (if so, then don't do what you're trying to do), or is this going to be run in a kiosk type situation (then you're OK)?

Comment: Have you googled -- Java kiosk mode osx -- ?  This returns some interesting and possibly helpful results.

Comment: yeah it will need to be JNI i'm pretty sure.  i've never made a JNI lib but i know the carbon and cocoa calls to make, so that's an option.  i'd have thought this would already exist though, as i imagine kiosks are pretty common in the processing world.  so i was hoping for some info.plist options or an existing lib :)

Comment: yeah i have been googling for a couple hours... i didn't find anything off-the-shelf (i did for fullscreen but nothing for locking down the keyboard) -- guess i should start researching jni.  of course if you see a decent link feel free to share :)

Comment: If it were my app, I'd try first with JNA before using JNI.  JNA's a lot easier to use and may be only very slightly slower than JNI.  But again, if this is not to be run on an independent kiosk machine, be wary as you'll have a lot of angry users out there! ;)

Comment: yeah it's a kiosk :)  thanks for the tip first i've heard of jna.  speed isn't a major concern so i'll check it out!

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your goal is noble: a kiosk-type setup on a computer that you have control of, not an app that a user would download.

If you can run your sketch as an applet you can open the html page in [Plainview](http://www.barbariangroup.com/software/plainview) (a free Webkit-based browser) set to kiosk mode. Plainview kiosk mode locks everything down with the system password.